# Изменить путь к .env

Tags: vue.js

Можно ли изменить расположение файлов с переменными .env во vuejs? Как это можно сделать?

`.env` файл лежит в корне проекта. Я хочу его перенести в другую директорию.

Comment: Я не совсем понял, что вы хотели сделать? Пожалуйста, приведите пример.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данный функционал не поддерживается разработчиками и противоречит [идеям](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2506) vuejs.